# save zip with a different file name using maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to be able to zip files in folder '${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/docker' to folder target/docker-files/docker-files.zip but currently they are getting saved in 'target/project-artifactId-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip'

I have written the following zip.xml file

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>docker_files</id>
<formats>
  <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
  <fileSet>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/docker</directory>
    <filtered>true</filtered>
    <outputDirectory>/docker-files-zip</outputDirectory>
  </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

My pom.xml has the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <fileName>docker-files</fileName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Any leads would be really helpful.